# How to send push notification based on timing in xamarin forms via firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to send push notification in xamarin forms via firebase, we are developing a chat application using xamarin forms in visual studio 2017, Home page what we have is, we have multiple options like entertainment, sports, education,etc(group listview). Admin added a one sports topic as cricket with timing 6 to 7 pm (He will be available in that timing). some user like to add a wish list cricket topic so that user will call in between 6 - 7 to admin, 
i need to send push notification admin and user(who is added wishlist) before 10 minites like 5:50, Give me a suggestion to resolve this issue

Comment: Just write a `Web-API` with a `Scheduler`, both easily available on the internet!

Comment: Thank you for quick reply hakim, i am totally new into web api so that give me a sample for creating web api with scheduler so that i can research right way

Comment: Sure this is a good example https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/application-scheduler-service-using-C-Sharp-net-and-xml/

Comment: Thanks hakim. Now I am working on it, if i have any doubt let you know

Comment: If you have solved your issue, please post your solution as an answer and accept it so this questions gets marked as answered. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered.

Comment: Sure Leon Lu, Once i finished then i will put solution

Comment: Ok, thanks for your update.